# function to return the opacity of div using YUI

Tags: yui

Using YUI API, how to write a function to return the opacity of this html object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YUI 3.x

```
Y.one("div").getStyle("opacity");
Y.one("div").getComputedStyle("opacity");
```